# type casting to more specific type

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have the following problem. Let's say I have the following two classes: Bicycle a MountainBike. In the header of MountainBike I state: `public class MountainBike extends Bicycle`. The MountainBike class adds two fields not present in Bicycle. Because I add the attributes one by one (because I'm working with a database), there is no constructor but a function which sets the attributes given a String identifier and a value. I know it is possible that not all attributes are set and could be null, but this is ok for me.

Now the question is the following. At a given point I know what type of bike it is, it is one of the fields. What I would like to do is the following: as soon as I know that this Bicycle object is in fact a MountainBike, I would like to cast it to MountainBike: `MountainBike mb = (MountainBike) bicycle`, however this results in a runtime java.lang.ClassCastException: Bicycle cannot be cast to MountainBike.

I'm sure this is possible (without using a constructor with the entire bicycle as argument). How can I do this?

Thank you!

Héctor

Comment: No, if you're getting an exception that's because the object you're working with *is* just a `Bicycle`. You can't change the type of an object after creation.

Comment: Ok thank you very much I'll try this. Is there an efficient way of setting all attributes (I have over a hundred!) from the bicycle to the mountainbike?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't create a MountainBike to start with?

Comment: Because it also could be a racing bicycle or something else :)

Comment: Well it's not really very clear where the data is coming from, and why you can't work out what it's meant to represent when you first create the object.

Comment: Well the data is coming in from a textfile, but not all data is present in this file. About halfway the file I get the info on which class it is, but if I want to create the specific objects beforehand I need to first read in the ENTIRE file (which is big) to get the classes and then go over the file again to get the actual data. Because this isn't an SQL database I cannot select a specific column, so either I need to read the textfile twice or I convert the objects halfway...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Jon Skeet said in his comment, you can't cast it if it isn't a `MountainBike` and is just a plain `Bicycle`. What you *can* do is create a constructor in `MountainBike` that takes `Bicycle` as a parameter:

```
public MountainBike(Bicycle bicycle) {
    // Copy bicycle's properties
}
```

And call it instead:

```
MountainBike mb = new MountainBike(Bicycle bicycle);
```

If you can't modify the `MountainBike` class for whatever reason, you can also create a `static` factory method:

```
public class MountainBikeFactory {

    public static MountainBike createMountainBike(Bicycle bicycle) {
        MountainBike mb = new MountainBike();
        // Copy bicycle's properties
        return mb;
    }
}
```

And to call it:

```
MountainBike mb = MountainBikeFactory.create(bicycle);
```

**Edit:** After looking at the info you posted as a comment on the question, it looks like you could try the builder pattern. The builder would contain all the attributes as variables (yes, it will be long at 100+ variables) and as you discover the attributes from your file, set them on the builder. Then, at the end, when you call the builder's `build()` method, have it resolve which type of bike to create and use polymorphism to handle groups of attributes w.r.t. which bike you created.

For example:

```
public class BikeBuilder {
    private String model;
    private String wheelSize;
    private String shocks;
    private String racingHandleBarType;

    // returns "this" so you can chain calls, common in builders, not necessary
    public BikeBuilder setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
        return this;
    }

    // Other setters

    public Bike build() {
        Bike bike;
        // Determine which kind of bike it is and create it
        if (shocks != null) {
            bike = new MountainBike();
            handleMountainBike((MountainBike) bike);
        } else if (racingHandleBarType != null) {
            bike = new RacingBike();
            handleRacingBike((RacingBike) bike);
        } else {
            bike = new Bike();
        }
        handleCommonAttributes(bike);
        return bike;
    }

    // All bikes have these attributes
    private void handleCommonAttributes(Bike bike) {
        bike.setModel(model);
        bike.setWheelSize(wheelSize);
    }

    private void handleMountainBike(MountainBike bike) {
        bike.setShocks(shocks);
    }

    private void handleRacingBike(RacingBike bike) {
        bike.setRacingHandleBarType(racingHandleBarType);
    }
}
```

This allows you to build the bike on the fly and decide its type at the end of reading in your file instead of the beginning. It serves as a sort of container. If you have multiple types that extend `Bike` you can create new methods for them. This will at least get you started.

Comment: Ok thank you very much I'll try this. Is there an efficient way of setting all attributes (I have over a hundred!) from the bicycle to the mountainbike?

Comment: Do the classes follow bean conventions, such as `getProperty` (or `isProperty` for `boolean`) and `setProperty` for each field?

Comment: no unfortunately they don't, just a big sequence of String attributes

Comment: Can you update your question with a more specific definition of "big sequence of String attributes"? This could be `List<String>`, `Map<String, String>`, `List<Pair<String, String>>`, etc.

Comment: No actually it is a sequence of the following form: String s1, s2, s3, s4, ..., s100
If it were an actual list it would be trivial :)

Comment: @HéctorvandenBoorn See my edit. It's not the prettiest solution, but it's relatively functional and extensible.

Answer (score 2):

In case you doubt that the cast can fail check before:

```
if (bike instanceof MountainBike) {
    MountainBike mb = (MountainBike) bike
} else {
    String msg = "Wrong bike, expected Mountainbike but was:" + bike.getClass();

    System.out.println(msg);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just cast a Bike to a MountainBike just because MountainBike extends Bike.  Here's an example:

```
Bike bike = new MountainBike();
MountainBike mb = (MountainBike) bike; //works

Bike bike = new Bike();
MountainBike mb = (MountainBike) bike; //ClassCastException
```